# PyQT dateTimeEdit подтянуть настоящею дату

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Необходимо в PyQT `dateTimeEdit` подтягивать настоящею на момент открытие программы дату. Сейчас там потягивается дата, что установлена в *Qt designer*, и постоянно надо будет перекручивать весь календарь в поисках нужной даты, что выглядит не очень интересно.

Код в блоке оформления

```
self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(parent=self.frame)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.StyleStrategy.PreferAntialias)
self.dateTimeEdit.setFont(font)
self.dateTimeEdit.setProperty("showGroupSeparator", True)
self.dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2023, 10, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
self.dateTimeEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate(2023, 10, 1))
self.dateTimeEdit.setMinimumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2023, 10, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
self.dateTimeEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(2025, 12, 31))
self.dateTimeEdit.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.Section.MonthSection)
self.dateTimeEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
self.dateTimeEdit.setCurrentSectionIndex(1)
self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
```

Пробовал уже в рабочем классе установить `QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()` но это не привело желаемому результату, ругается.

```
self.ui.dateTimeEdit(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime)
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work\Auxilium infirmi\auxilium_infirmi_funk.py", line 161, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Work\Auxilium infirmi\auxilium_infirmi_funk.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.ui.dateTimeEdit(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime)
TypeError: 'QDateTimeEdit' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code
```

1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, ошибка здесь:

```
self.ui.dateTimeEdit(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime)
```

Эту строку нужно удалить.

А вот эту добавить:

```
self.dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
```

Код полностью:

```
self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(parent=self.frame)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.StyleStrategy.PreferAntialias)
self.dateTimeEdit.setFont(font)
self.dateTimeEdit.setProperty("showGroupSeparator", True)
self.dateTimeEdit.setMinimumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2023, 10, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
self.dateTimeEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(2025, 12, 31))
self.dateTimeEdit.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.Section.MonthSection)
self.dateTimeEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
self.dateTimeEdit.setCurrentSectionIndex(1)
self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")

# Установка текущей даты и времени
self.dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
```

Comment: Да, сказать "Установи"  `setDateTime` я и забыл.